# Krakenex API multiple pairs query

Tags: python, api, cryptography

I am trying to use the Krakenex python library to query the order book for multiple currency pairs at once. When I do it for a single currency is works, like this:

```
con = krakenex.API()
con.load_key('kraken.key')
con.query_public('Depth', {'pair':'GNOETH'})
```

However, if I do:

```
con = krakenex.API()
con.load_key('kraken.key')
con.query_public('Depth', {'pair':['GNOETH', 'GNOEUR']})
```

I get `{'error': ['EQuery:Unknown asset pair']}`. I assume that the syntax is incorrect but can't figure out the correct one. This is the first time that I use an API and the example provided are not covering enough info yet.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can not query the `Depth` of multiple asset pairs with a single request. I had the same question to Kraken's support: their reason not allowing it, is high computational cost.

On contrary, querying e.g. `AssetPairs` endpoint in the same manner works.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time trying different combos, finally figured it out.

try `con.query_public('Depth', {'pair':'GNOETH, GNOEUR'})`