# Kraken.com API - Adding more pairs to Ticker array

Tags: php, arrays, kraken.com

I'm trying to add multiple pairs to the array below but I can only retrieve the last pair. So how can I get both pairs / add more pairs?

```
$ticker = $kraken->QueryPublic('Ticker', array('pair' => 'XXBTZEUR', 'pair' => 'XXRPXXBT'));

print "<pre>";
print_r($ticker);
print "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

> Notice: Undefined index: XXBTZEUR in /home/... on line 14

Array

```
(
    [error] => Array
        (
        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [XXRPXXBT] => Array
                (
                    [a] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.000028120
                            [1] => 10836
                            [2] => 10836.000
                        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this associated array:

```
array('pair' => 'XXBTZEUR', 'pair' => 'XXRPXXBT')
```

An associated array is a set of key-value pairs. The key identifies the value. Since your key of `pair` is duplicate here, the latter abrogates the former. You will probably need to do as many queries as the number of pairs you need to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is an answer here for a similar question, but it's in Python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488326/krakenex-api-multiple-pairs-query. I've tried different other combinations, but no luck. As you mentioned it, I may just need to do as many queries as the number of pairs I need.

Comment: @Seb it is highly probable that this is the situation. However, I think that you need to implement this as a function that is reusable, portable and clear-cut. That would ensure that if the feature we are missing here will be available some time in the future, then you can apply it as simply as changing the array values.